# What happens to the returned value by class body?

Tags: scala

Let the following scala class:

```
case class Foo(i:Int) {
  println("from Foo: "+i)
  None /* (A) */
}
```

used with this trivial main :

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val t = new Foo(12)
    println(t)
  }
}
```

Prints :

```
from Foo: 12
Foo(12)
```

I can replace the line marked by `/* (A) */`,  `None` by `1612`  or `new StringBuilder`, the behaviour is still the same.

What happens to this last value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. It is useless. It is a call that is not assigned and has no side effects. The garbage collector will delete this object or maybe the compiler will eliminate the call.

Please notice, that this is NOT the end of the constructor, but the class body. This `(i:Int)` is the entire constructor.

Comment: so with this is not an error ? or even a warning compilation ? why letting some value on stack is permitted ?

Comment: The compiler can not know this in general. Your code could have side effects. Calling any of your options have not.

Comment: It might be that you want to create the object for side effects.

Comment: Made a edit to point out, that you are talking about the class body, not the constructor.